# Conversion from String to BigDecimal do not with Cucumber on Scala

Tags: scala, cucumber

I'm writing tests in Cucumber for Scala code. I have following step

```
When added product with price 10.0
```

And following step definition:

```
When( """^added product with price ([\d\.]*)$""") {
    (price: BigDecimal) => {
     //something
  }
}
```

I get following error when I run test from IntelliJ:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Don't know how to convert "10.0" into scala.math.BigDecimal.
Try writing your own converter:

@cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamConverter(BigDecimalConverter.class)
public class BigDecimal {}

  at cucumber.runtime.ParameterInfo.convert(ParameterInfo.java:104)
  at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.transformedArgs(StepDefinitionMatch.java:70)
  at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:38)
  at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:289)
  at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
  at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
  at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
  at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:116)
  at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:120)
  at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:108)
  at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:26)
  at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:16)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I have tried to implement my own Transformer but I can't adnotate scala.math.BigDecimal

```
class BigDecimalConverter extends  Transformer[BigDecimal] {
  override def transform(p1: String): BigDecimal = BigDecimal(p1)
}
```

Do you have any suggestion why Cucumber is not loading cucumber.runtime.xstream.BigDecimalConverter?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I'm passing String and create BigDecimal using it.

```
When( """^added product with price ([\d\.]*)$""") {
  (price: String) => {
    something(BigDecimal(price))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is impossible to use BigDecimal as an expected parameter type for Step.

After some research I've come to the next possible solution, if the goal is to use BigDecimal without converting it from String (as per 'workaround' provided in previous answer.

1. Create Transformer class with a BigDecimal wrapped in the custom MyBigDecimal case class:

   ```
   import cucumber.api.{Transformer}
   import cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamConverter

   class MyBigDecimalTransformer extends Transformer[MyBigDecimal] {
       override def transform(value: String): MyBigDecimal = {
           MyBigDecimal(BigDecimal(value))
   }}

   @XStreamConverter(classOf[MyBigDecimalTransformer])
   case class MyBigDecimal(value: BigDecimal) {
   }
   ```
2. Then it is possible to use it in step definitions:

   ```
   When( """^added product with price ([\d\.]*)$""") {
   (price: MyBigDecimal) => {
    //something
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: I have this problem for all case classes which is really disappointing. If I own the case class, I can provide my own converter but even that is painful.